# Automated tests for Chinese browsers: Sogou Explorer, QQ, 360 and Baidu

Tags: javascript, automation, software-testing, quality-assurance

Is there any possibility to test web apps in these Chinese browsers:  Sogou Explorer, QQ, 360 and Baidu? (even one of them would be good)

Of course [webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) would be great but it seems there’s no such possibility.

Environment doesn’t matter (preferred Linux, but all systems are ok).
Preferred language is Java, but can be any language as well.
Open source would be good, but any paid soft is welcome of course.

I just need anything that works with these browsers or at least one of them.

Comment: What do you mean with *testing Chinese browsers*?

Comment: Sorry, of course I mean writing automated tests for web app and run on those browsers to check if app works OK.

Comment: Automated test for what? How long it takes to crash? What information is leaked where to? How well a certain feature set is covered? How good they stick to defined standards? What tests are specific to *Chinese* browsers but not to others?

Comment: I’d like to write some test scenarios like in webdriver (click buttons in web app, type some text in text fields and so on - only basic actions) and make sure there’s no JS issues, remote content is downloaded and displayed - basic web app automation only.

Comment: I don't need to simulate poor network and other variables, inject JS, run simultaneously on grid or add some native steps for custom controls - only basic web automation in these browsers.

Comment: Please edit all your comment answers into your question, then remove them

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [SikuliX](http://sikulix.com/) which allows testing of just about anything by actually looking at the screen and locating controls to operate, comparing the results, etc. with images.

As such it doesn't require any internal knowledge of the browser, page content, etc. - Your script tells it to issue commands, look for and operate controls, etc.

To quote the website:

SikuliX supports as scripting languages

- Python language level 2.7 (supported by Jython)
- running RobotFramework text-scripts is supported (see docs)
- Ruby language level 1.9 and 2.0 (supported by JRuby)
- JavaScript (supported by the Java Scripting Engine)

… and you can use it in Java programming and programming/scripting with any Java aware programming/scripting language (Jython, JRuby, Scala, Clojure, …).